# Handling GWT's UmbrellaException with multiple causes

Tags: java, gwt, exception

While trying to implement full client error logging for **GWT** application, I've stumbled upon following question with well known **UmbrellaException**:

Because **UmbrellaException** can have multiple **causes**, how they should be treated?

**Most** (if not all) **blogs & answers** I've found so far on this topic **assumed** that there is either **1 or 0 causes**. Is it always like that or it is false assumption?

After reading [UmbrellaException JavaDoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/UmbrellaException.html) it looks like it's just a "package" of not related thrown exceptions.

So in theory, one should treat **UmbrellaException** with N **causes** like N separate thrown exceptions?

Also, as far as I understood, **UmbrellaException** usually comes as first exception in chain i.e. it shouldn't come inside exception chain if treated correctly, is it right?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer to the following question helps to understand, how UmbrellaExceptions can be handled: [GWT client umbrellaexception get full error message in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029002/gwt-client-umbrellaexception-get-full-error-message-in-java/11033699#11033699)

Comment: @Balder yes, I thought about simply iterating over all causes and print their stack trace. However, I would like to find more documentation on how these exceptions should be treated and in what combinations they can be thrown from GWT